# ANGULAR PWA - sending request in background

Tags: angular, mobile, progressive-web-apps, angular-service-worker

I'm developing an Angular PWA that can work offline for short periods of time, but I need it to send a request to the server every 10 minutes to keep the session active. While the app is open on my mobile device, I have no issues, but when the app goes into the background, the calls are no longer made because the timer is interrupted.

What technology should I use to ensure that requests are made even when the app is in the background?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.